# ListPlot vs. ListLinePlot How Do You Remove Discontinuous Artefacts from Introduced by Mod?

Tags: plotting, modular-arithmetic

I have some data that inherently describes a phase and would like to plot it in between [0, 2*pi).

When I use `ListPlot` with the `Mod[data, 2*pi]` function, it nicely transforms the data and plots it between [0, 2*pi) (first image). However, when I use `ListLinePlot`, artefacts are introduced that connect the points being wrapped around the circle (second image). Is there a way to eliminate these so that these jumps aren't connected? The actual dataset I have is quite large, so looking for each jump manually is unfortunately out of the questions. Thanks!

```
data = {{-0.00398448, 0.0353995}, {-0.00582442, 0.0336297}, {-0.00821678, 0.0313288}, {-0.0113276, 0.0283377}, {-0.0153729, 0.0244491}, {-0.0199987, 0.0200038}, {-0.0206339, 0.0193936}, {-0.0270866, 0.0131959}, {-0.033543, 0.00699781}, {-0.0400031, 0.00079947}, {-0.0464668, -0.00539914}}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use "Mod" with an offset:

```
ListLinePlot[Mod[data, 2 Pi, -Pi], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Daniel! Thanks for your response! From my understanding off the offset in the Mod function, does it not just give a result within the region of the offset? When I use your example with my full dataset, for example, it just shifts the whole curve, including the discontinuities, into the region bound by [-pi, pi]. However, I want to keep all of my data in the [0, 2*pi) region -- just without the artefacts that have been introduced via ListLinePlot vs. ListPlot.

Comment: First, you are right, with an offset the range is shifted by the offset. However, you can not have it both ways. If you specify a range from 0 to 2Pi, then everything is in this region. If anything is  above 2Pi will be shifted by -2Pi. What you could do, is to plot the outlier separately and combine the plots. Or you could use different "Mod" for different points.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the idea of plotting separately and combining is quite clever -- will give that a go!